# How to find the cdf of R = U^2 < 1/4?

Tags: probability-theory

A number U is chosen at random in the interval [0,1]. Find the probability that (a) R = U^2 < 1/4.

Attempt: For this one, I was a little confused with the (1/4) near the function, so I thought about using P(Y < than or = to y), then I thought about plugging it in to obtain P(U^2< or = to r), then I thought about adding (1/4) on both sides to get P(U^2+(1/4)< or = to r+(1/4)), Then I thought about doing an integration to obtain 2*r^(1/2), but the back of the book said it was not the correct answer. How should you find the correct CDF?

Comment: ?? $[R<\frac14]=[U<\frac12]$. Likewise, for every $r$ in $(0,1)$,  $[R<r]=[U<\sqrt r]$.

Comment: You know, sooner or later you will have to learn the definitions... How many questions already, on this very situation?

Comment: Thank u for ur help! So if we have like R=U (1-U), then we would need to add (1/4) to both sides as we plug R into the theorem F (y)=p (Y <y)?

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: I wanted to know what to do if we have R=u (1-U)<(1/4), and if I were to try to find th e cdf, and eventually got P ( U^2-U> or = -y), by then, would I need to add (1/4) to both sides to solve this?

Comment: FYI, R=U(1-U) is **always** <(1/4)... No idea either what "to add (1/4) to both sides" could mean.